# ¿Cual es el error presente en el código?

Tags: c

¿Si quiero hacer que el código identifique los números primos y no primos como lo puedo corregir para que sea coherente? ya que me muestra erróneamente el tipo de numero. Creo que mi error radica en el if final, espero que puedan orientarme ya que soy nuevo en este lenguaje.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int numeros_divisores(n){
int i=1;
int cont=0;
while(i<n){
        if(n%1==0){

            cont=cont+1;
        }
    i=i+1;
}
return cont;

}

  int main()
{
  int n;
  int respuesta;

printf("Ingrese un numero para identificar si es primo \n");
scanf("%d",&n);
respuesta = numeros_divisores(n);

if(respuesta < 2){
    printf("El valor ingresado es primo");

}
else
    printf("El valor ingresado no es primo");

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Estas fueron las líneas de código necesarias para su correcto funcionamiento.

```
   if(n%i==0)

     
if(respuesta <= 2)
```